# What is the right way to merge multiple branches having thousands of files changed

Tags: git, merge

I have below requirement which I am not sure about how to do it in proper way:

- 5 different branches, all derived from master
- all worked on by different developers, and I need to merge them into one and then push it into master.

I tried merging them one by one, but since 2 of them contain thousands of files as updated (lots of them are auto generated), I am not able to check if merge is correct and no changes are lost.

What would be a correct way to merge all these?

I tried to merge them one by one, using below:

- created my own branch from master, say `my_branch`, by `git checkout my_branch`
- merged branch A by `git merge A`
- similary, merged B, C, D, E.

But since D & E contain thousands of files, I am not sure how to check that none of the changes are lost.
Merge conflicts were very few.

Comment: It's not clear why autogenerated files need to be kept in source control in the first place, rather than being created as part of the build process.

Comment: @chepner yeah.. we are currently fixing that thing. I have fixed all the conflicts. I would like to build, do some testing and send it to Testing team. Just want to be sure I am not missing any thing, as all these files contain too many changes.

Comment: How did the developers confirm the code on their branches was correct, before you merged them in? (Whatever they did, you could repeat after the merge too.)